# Reutilizar código con variables booleanas distintas

Tags: java, botón, boolean, eficiencia

Buen día a todos, estoy haciendo un TPV en Java para clase. De momento me funciona como yo quiero, el problema es que tengo varios botones para registrar bebidas en un JTable llamado tblProductos.

Los botones funcionan de esta manera, si pulsas una vez una coca cola por ejemplo y ese producto no está en la tabla, lo registra, y si ya existe sobrescribe la cantidad y le añade + 1 y el precio total que es el resultado de 
mi variable precioUnidad(que es lo que vale cada producto) * cantidad.

Cada botón tiene su propia variable booleana por defecto a false para saber si ese botón se ha pulsado.

Es demasiado código, ¿se os ocurre alguna forma de hacer mi código más eficiente? Para no tener que recurrir al copiar y pegar puro y duro.

```
public class TPV extends javax.swing.JFrame {

private String nombre;
private int cantidad;
private double precioUnidad;

protected static DefaultTableModel modelo;

boolean pulsadoSprite = false;
boolean pulsadoCocaCola = false;

public void insertarProd() {
    modelo.addRow(new Object[{nombre,cantidad,precioUnidad,formateoPrecioPack});
}

public void sumarCant() {
    for (int i = 0; i < modelo.getRowCount(); i++) {
        if(nombre.equalsIgnoreCase(modelo.getValueAt(i, 0).toString())) {
           int cantidadAux = (int)tblProductos.getValueAt(i, 1);
           cantidadAux = cantidadAux + 1;
           tblProductos.setValueAt(cantidadAux, i, 1);//La columna 1 es la cantidad
           tblProductos.setValueAt(cantidadAux * precioUnidad, i, 3);//La columna 3 es del precio total
        }
    }
}

private void btnCocaColaActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
    nombre = "Coca Cola";
    precioUnidad = 0.81;

    if(pulsadoCocaCola){
        sumarCant();
    }else{
        cantidad = 1;
        insertarProd();
        pulsadoCocaCola = true;
    }
}

private void btnSpriteActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    nombre = "Sprite";
    precioUnidad = 0.90;

    if(pulsadoSprite){
        sumarCant();
    }else{
        cantidad = 1;
        agregarProducto();
        pulsadoSprite = true;
    }
}
```

Muchas gracias, de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que puedo observar de tu código, es bastante difícil escalar la aplicación porque eso que estas mencionando sera un problema recurrente cuando quieras mejorarla. 
Revisa la filosofía modelo-vista-controlador. Trata de crear clases que contengan los algoritmos para cálculos, otro para llenar la tabla y uno para contener los atributos de interés, luego instancialas desde la vista las veces que sean necesarias. Evita crear variables estáticas.

EJM:

```
public class Productos {
private String nombre;
private int cantidad;
private double precioUnidad;

public Productos(String nombre, int cantidad, double precioUnidad) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.cantidad = cantidad;
    this.precioUnidad = precioUnidad;
}

public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}

public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}

public int getCantidad() {
    return cantidad;
}

public void setCantidad(int cantidad) {
    this.cantidad = cantidad;
}

public double getPrecioUnidad() {
    return precioUnidad;
}

public void setPrecioUnidad(double precioUnidad) {
    this.precioUnidad = precioUnidad;
}
```

}

Luego hacemos una clase para manipular la tabla y agregar los datos

```
public class TablaProductos {

private List<Productos> elementos;
private JTable tabla;
private DefaultTableModel modelo;

public TablaProductos(List<Productos> elementos, JTable tabla) {
    this.elementos = elementos;
    this.tabla = tabla;

    this.inicializarTabla();
}

public void inicializarTabla(){
    modelo = new DefaultTableModel(0, 3);
    modelo.addColumn("Nombre");
    modelo.addColumn("Cantidad");
    modelo.addColumn("PrecioUnitario");

    tabla.setModel(modelo);
}

public void insertarProducto(){
   elementos.stream()
            .forEach(items -> {
                modelo.addRow(new Object[]{items.getNombre(), items.getCantidad(), items.getPrecioUnidad()});

            });
}
```

}

Ahora solo te quedan los algoritmos para los cálculos.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, intentaré hacer lo que me dices, cuando empiece Navidad que ando entregando trabajos y de exámenes. Una duda, si quisiera usar un JTable que ya tengo definido en mi JFrame, está posicionado de forma gráfica con el NetBeans, ¿cómo podría hacerlo?

Comment: Es simple trata de hacer una clase que puedas reutilizar las veces que quieras pero solo para insertar valores o manipular la tabla. Una clase solo dedicada para eso....Solo le pasarías 2 parámetros. la tabla y la otra los datos....Agarra la clase que se llama TablaProductos....y ponle un nombre mas genérico y solo modificala a conveniencia....de tal forma que la puedas aplicar a cualquier tabla para manipular datos. Es super útil así.